# Erro Converter data formato BR

Tags: python, pandas

Tentando converter str para data no formato BR mas da erro  abaixo. E se eu tiro ‘format’ ele vai no formato americano:

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘df.csv',encoding='cp1252', sep=';')

df['Data']= pd.to_datetime('31/09/2019  11:13:01', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

> Erro: ValueError: day is out of range for month

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a data 31/09/2019 não é válida (setembro só tem 30 dias).

Você pode passar o parâmetro `errors="ignore"` ou `errors="coerce"` para a função `to_datetime`.

Comment: Ótima observação.